# Gulp - Copy multiple files to seperate paths

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am working on a web app that uses Node.js. In this app, I have a Gulp file. I am using Gulp 4. During my build process, I am attempting to copy multiple files to directories at once. My directory structure looks like this:

```
./
  dest/
  source/
    child/
      index.js
      index.bak
    file.js
    README.md
```

My real directory structure is more involved. However, I am trying to copy `./source/file.js` to `./dest/file.js` and `./source/child/index.js` to `./dest/child/index.js`. Notice that I do not want to copy `README.md` or `index.bak` over to the `./dest directory`. In an attempt to do this, I have the following function:

```
function copy() {
  let files = [
    'source/file.js',
    'source/child/**/*.*'
  ];

  return gulp
    .src(files)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'))
  ;
}
```

My problem is, everything just gets copied to the `dest` directory. The directory structure does not get preserved. While would be fine if I could figure out how to copy files to different directories in a single task. I tried the following:

```
function copy() {
    return gulp
        .src('source/child/index.js')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/child'))
        .src('source/file.js')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'))
    ;            
}
```

However, that approach just generates an error that says:

```
TypeError: gulp.src(...).pipe(...).src is not a function
```

So, I'm stuck. I'm not sure how to copy multiple files to multiple directories from a single gulp task.

Comment: You can also try `gulp-if-esle plugin`

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the base option as mentioned here [ref](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl-fs#optionsbase). It will make sure your directory is copied as it is.

```
function copy() {
  let files = [
    'source/file.js',
    'source/child/**/*.*'
  ];

  return gulp
    .src(files, {base: 'source/'})
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
}
```

Comment: Wow! That's awesome. I had no idea about the parameters that could be passed to the src function. Thanks!